# How to tell if a file is added to a directory using perl?

Tags: perl, file, directory

Within a script want to track any new file added to a directory using perl, test to see if the file is a certain one I am looking for, and then stop watching the directory / continue actions based on the file in the program.

How best to proceed?

Comment: http://search.cpan.org/~mlehmann/Linux-Inotify2-1.22/Inotify2.pm

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: How do you "know it is the one you are looking for"?

Answer (score 0):

Like this?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
while(!-f "fred"){
   print "Waiting for fred\n";
   sleep 1;
}
print "There he is!!!\n"
```

Comment: Why the down vote? If you are going to down vote, at least have the decency to say why. I don't see anyone with a better suggestion, and this does what the OP said he was looking for and is portable across Linux/Windows.

Comment: It doesn't answer the question (by the way I didn't down vote but it doesn't answer it anyway) - this is just showing a file test operator.  The primary problem I'm having is how to automatically detect any new file that is added to a directory and pick that up within the script.

Comment: So, when you say "test to see if the file is a certain one I am looking for" that doesn't mean you know its name and you can't change "fred" in my script to whatever you are looking for. Maybe you could clarify how you will know it is the certain one you are looking for...

Comment: Whether it is fred or thelma there is no "streaming" connection to a directory so that we automatically know what files have been added, is there?

Comment: @user1849286, Yes, there is: Linux::Inotify and Win32::ChangeNotify

Comment: All I was trying to say is that if you know the name of the file, you can make life easier and your code more portable and do something like I suggested. But if you choose to stick with the rather vague and woolly description "the one I am looking for" and decline to say whether you know its name or not, then you'll have to go with one of @ikegami's suggestions.

Comment: Even if the filename is known in advance your answer does not address the main question - how to tell when the file has arrived in the directory.  @ikegami suggestion is a necessary first part of the code in order to see whether a file of a known name or otherwise has been created in the directory we are monitoring.  Like I say I didn't vote down anything, but I suspect I am articulating why others may have done.  Don't shoot the messenger.

Comment: Upvoted. It's not clever, but it clearly answers the question as asked. There's a long tradition of inefficient-but-simple being a good approach for small cases in unix development.

Comment: @user1849286, Re "Even if the filename is known in advance your answer does not address the main question - how to tell when the file has arrived in the directory.", Actually, it does.